# Can't see my wifi printer anymore

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, printer

I have a Windows 7 laptop, connected to my wifi network. I also have an `Epson Stylus Photo PX730WD` connected to the same wifi network.

Since few days (or weeks? as I don't print often), I am not able to print anything. The laptop does not find the printer anymore on the network.

When I look on the printer itself, it seems connected, the wifi report does not display any error. If I go on the administration site of my Neufbox (the internet box of my ISP), I can see three devices connected on the router (laptop, printer, iPhone). So I imagine that the printer is indeed connected to the network. However, I can't ping the printer from my laptop using its IP address.

I've tried to reinstall the drivers, to resetup the network connection on the printer, but still, the laptop does not find it, and I can't print anymore.

Note that everything works if I connect the printer with USB.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

*Little update* This printer is compatible with AirPrint, so I've tried to print something from my iPhone. But no luck, the iPhone does not find the printer on the network.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to find this model on the Epson site. How old is it? Have you tried unplugging the printer for a few minutes, then reconnected and powered it back on?

Comment: Only one year. You can find it here: http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/overview/10990

Comment: Thanks. I did a search with the model number but it did not find it. Have you been through these [Problem Solver](http://support.epson-europe.com/onlineguides/en/px730wd_nwg/html/probl_4.htm) steps? Try rebooting the router.

Comment: Rebooting didn't help (I've reboot the laptop, the printer, the router)

Comment: Have you tried to print a network configuration sheet from the Printer's configuration menu? You are probably trying to ping the wrong IP. It is possible your printer renewed its IP address and the computer has the printer added by IP instead of hostname.

Comment: No, I tried the good IP, given by the printer on his screen. That's strange because my iPhone or my laptop does not find the printer, but the router displays the information that says the printer is connected to the wifi network...

Comment: What is the IP address the printer is giving you?

Comment: It's 192.168.1.24

Comment: Have you tried to rerun the WiFi setup wizard on the printer? You may want to do a factory reset on the printer and rerun the Wifi setup wizard. Also, on your router, are you seeing the device as an active connected device or is it under the DHCP leases?

Comment: I've set the WIFI configuration again, then a full reset of the printer. It didn't help neither. On the router, it's on the active devices list.

Comment: On the router, do you have MAC address filtering setup? Is the router using WPS? What wireless security technology are you using?

Comment: @xxl3ww There is no MAC address filtering. The router uses WPA for the encryption.